# thumb generation on fly

Tags: php

I am using following code to convert large images into smaller one...

```
$filename= $_GET['filename'];
$width = $_GET['width'];
$height = $_GET['height'];
$path="http://localhost/pics/"; //finish in "/"


// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($path.$filename);

if ($width && ($width_orig < $height_orig)) {
   $width = ($height / $height_orig) * $width_orig;
} else {
   $height = ($width / $width_orig) * $height_orig;
}

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path.$filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);

// Imagedestroy
imagedestroy ($image_p);
```

And its working perfect, how can i cache images? please help me with that. thanks.

Comment: Unless you really want to learn to do it yourself - why not use an existing thumbnails library that does caching out of the box?

Comment: can you suggest me some please?

Comment: Google `php thumbnail generator` and use the first hit

Comment: i am using smarty btw, would that help for cache?

Comment: Nope, you need a separate thumbnail generator for this.

Answer (score 2):

Why not save thumbnail, then you can call thumbnails like this:

`'<img src="/path/to/cache/thumbnail.jg" />'`

I modify yor code for that:

```
<?php
$filename= $_GET['filename'];
$width = $_GET['width'];
$height = $_GET['height'];
$path="http://localhost/pics/"; //finish in "/"



// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($path.$filename);

if ($width && ($width_orig < $height_orig)) {
   $width = ($height / $height_orig) * $width_orig;
} else {
   $height = ($width / $width_orig) * $height_orig;
}

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path.$filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p,'/path/to/cache/'.$filename, 100);

// Imagedestroy
imagedestroy ($image_p);

?>
```

Comment: if you delete/update large image, so you must delete/update the thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument for [imagejpeg](https://www.php.net/imagejpeg) is the $filename to save the image to. Just save your images to disk.

Comment: i am using smarty, would that help for cache?

Comment: The point of a cache is to prevent the script from having to run for each request. Storing the image to disk will achieve that. All you have to do is check if(file_exists('/path/to/cache/'.$filename)) before running your thumbnail code. I haven't used Smarty in a long time, so it may have some way to deal with this, but IMO you're much better off keeping it simple.

Answer (score 0):

In my oppinion, the best way to cache images is using [eTag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).

More info on [Yahoo!](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Is not easy to setup a minimal [CND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) but it boosts your website!

I'm pretty sure there are a lot of minimal scripts that can help you get started.